# Deserialize large json data with 30 blob objects

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a webservice which Returns me an json string.
Alltogehter I have 432 JSON Objects with blob data.
In each Webrequest I get 30 Objects of 432, till iam at 432 .
For each deserialization the time to deserialize increases.
30 Objects Need 9 seconds, in second deserilization we need 15 seconds.
463 Objects are 1,3 GB.

How can I adjust my Code, that the 30 Objects not need 9 Seconds and more ?

The String Looks like the following:

```
{
  "d:" [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "groesse": 2515221,
      "byteasbase64string": "the base64 string"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "groesse": 887748,
      "byteasbase64string": "the base64 string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Heres my c# Code:

```
List<db.dwaprotokolldatei> getProtokolldatei = new List<db.dwaprotokolldatei>();
using (postStreamGPD = resGPD.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (srGPD = new StreamReader(postStreamGPD))
    {
        string responseFromServerGPD = srGPD.ReadToEnd(); // Long running time
        getProtokolldatei = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<db.rootobject>(responseFromServerGPD).d;// Long running time
        responseFromServerGPD = "";
    }
}

reqGPD = null;
postDataAsBytesGPD = null;
postStreamGPD.Dispose();
postStreamGPD = null;
resGPD.Dispose();
resGPD = null;
srGPD.Dispose();
srGPD = null;

GC.Collect();
```

WebRequest:

```
reqGPD = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("*****");
                        reqGPD.Method = "POST";
                        reqGPD.ContentType = "application/json";
               mobileJSON = ConvertTOJSONMobile(existingMobile);

                        postDataAsBytesGPD = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mobileJSON);
                        postStreamGPD = reqGPD.GetRequestStream();
                        postStreamGPD.Write(postDataAsBytesGPD, 0, postDataAsBytesGPD.Length);
                        postStreamGPD.Flush();
                        postStreamGPD.Dispose();

                            resGPD = reqGPD.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Just for your information - wrapping something in a `using` construct like that already calls the `Dispose()` method on the wrapped instance (in your case, `postStreamGPD` and `srGPD`). You don't need to do it manually.

Comment: Okay, but that will not solve my Problem.

Comment: No, which is why I didn't give it as an answer, just a comment. =)

Comment: From your code-comment, it's not the deserialisation that takes time, it's the actual downloading of the data. Is that correct? If it is, you might want to clarify that in your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: When I call srGPD.ReadToEnd(); we already have the data from webservice right? So I think that we dont download the data.

Comment: The ReadToEnd method is what downloads the data, reading the stream. That it takes time to download 1.3 GB of data is understandable.

Comment: Ahh okay, but why does the time increase?
First time we need 5-9 seconds but for the second one, we need more than 15 seconds.

Comment: That entirely depends on what you're doing with your request. Maybe the payload is actually larger for each request?

Comment: I edited my Question with the WebRequest.
For every request i get exactly 30 Objects back. The different can be the data size, because blob data has different large.

Answer (score 0):

in web config you need that:

```
<configuration> 
       <system.web.extensions>
           <scripting>
               <webServices>
                   <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
               </webServices>
           </scripting>
       </system.web.extensions>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: The Problem ist not from webservice. In Client i get the objects from webservice call. Here is the Problem, the time for ReadToEnd increases in my for.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try parallelizing it?

```
        List<db.dwaprotokolldatei> getProtokolldatei = new List<db.dwaprotokolldatei();
        Parallel.ForEach(urls, url =>
        {
            var str = GetStringFromWebService(url);
            getProtokolldatei.AddRange(Deserialize(str));
            DisposeAll();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

ReadToEnd() is much faster.

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```